# Youtube video as full background with min-width and min-height

Tags: css, html, youtube, html5-video

I would like a full size, background youtube video. I used the [following example](http://codepen.io/mattgrosswork/pen/jrdwK) for html5 video, and it worked.

I would like same, resizable background video, but unfortunately black bar appears on both side.

The solution is for html5 videos are the following snippet:

```
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
position: aboslute;
```

What's the problem with it with youtube videos? What is the best way to get same result?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #333;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

#video-background {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto; 
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
}

article {

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<article>

  <h1>GROSS DESIGN co.</h1>
</article>

<video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted>
  <source src="http://beta.mattgrossdesign.com/sites/default/files/wood%20autumn-HD.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try another approach with Jquery; It would allow you to have your youtube videos auto-resize based on the browser viewport. Put your content in the DIV and use it as a container.

[Original Tutorial](http://www.skipser.com/p/2/p/auto-resize-youtube-videos-in-responsive-layout.html)